# Graphics Magick with Node - creating a cropped thumbnail without reducing image quality

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing, graphicsmagick

I have some code which crops an image and centers it using Graphics Magick. However the resulting image has a reduced fidelity. I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to avoid the reduction in quality?

```
  gm(imagePath)
    .thumbnail(25, 25 + '^')
    .gravity('Center')
    .extent(25, 25)
    .write(imagePath, function (error) {
      if (error) console.log('Error - ', error);
      callback()
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `.quality()` method to your chainStack, like this:

```
 gm(imagePath)
    .thumbnail(25, 25 + '^')
    .quality(100)
    .gravity('Center')
    .extent(25, 25)
    .write(imagePath, function (error) {
      if (error) console.log('Error - ', error);
      callback()
    });
```

Of course you can play with the quality % to suit your needs.

Here is the function reference:

http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#quality
http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-quality